# constructing char*const* from string

Tags: c++, c, string, char, constants

I am trying to convert a string to a `const*char*` in order to be able to call a library function. My code is as follows:

```
// myVec is simply a vector<string> 

vector<string> myVec;
/* stuff added to myVec
 * it is a vector of words that were seperated by whitespace
 * for example myVec[0]=="Hey"; myVec[1]=="Buck"; myVec[2]=="Rogers"; etc...
 */

char*const* myT = new char*[500]; //I believe my problem stems from here

for(int z=0; z<myVec.size(); z++) {
   string temp=myVec[z]+=" "; 
   myT[z]=temp.c_str();
}
//execv call here
```

I am constructing this for the second parameter of [`execv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp).

Compiler always throws various errors, and when I fix one another one pops up (seems rather circular from the solutions/google-fu I have employed).

Comment: That won't be a good idea, as the `temp` variable is just what you named it, temporary. That means that the pointer returned by `c_str` is also temporary.

Comment: temp is fine, as the exec call will be right after this code; I don't know why I left the new in there for myT, I have just been bangin my head trying to get this to work

Comment: Not really, as the lifetime of the `temp` variable is only inside the loops current iteration. Once you continue to the next iteration, or leave the loop, that stack memory can (and will) be reclaimed by the compiler.

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to allocate 500 pointers, as you have the size of the vector. Just remember to allocate one extra entry for the array, as the array needs to be terminated by a null pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of `execv` expects the array of arguments to point to modifyable C style strings. So contrary to what the other answers suggest, `c_str()` is not such a good idea.

While not guaranteed in C++03, the fact is that all implementations of `std::string` that I know of store the data in a contiguous NULL terminated block of memory (this is guaranteed in C++11), so you can use that to your advantage: Create a vector of pointers to modifiable character arrays, initialize the values with the buffers for the strings in your input vector and pass the address of that block of data to `execv`:

```
std::vector<char*> args;
args.reserve(myVec.size()+1);
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it=myVec.begin(); it != myVec.end(); ++it) {
   args.push_back(&((*it)[0]);
}
args.push_back(0);   // remember the null termination:

execv("prog", &args[0]);
```

Comment: Ouch.  Does `execv` really want to modify the data in situ?  Why?  Or is this just a case where someone forgot a `const`, and we can safely work around it with a `const_cast`?  (LOgically, `execv` cannot change any of the characters present in the strings, and it cannot add characters, since it has no guarantee that the space is there, so I don't see how it could modify the data.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I don't know of any good reason, but the documentation claims that the second argument is of type `char * const *`. The fact that there is a `const` in there indicates that this is not just an old API that did not know about `const`, so I won't assume it does not mangle with the data...

Comment: I suspect (but I have no inside information with regards to Posix) that they simply copied the signature which gets passed to `main`.  And in `main`, you _do_ have a right to change the strings (but not the array of pointers), which explains the somewhat strange signature.  Anyway, playing it safe, you're right; you'll nned to use `&((*it)[0])` instead of `it->c_str()`.  (But you could still do it using `std::transform`.)

Comment: Note too that if you preconstruct `args` to the correct initial size, the code is simpler: you don't need the `reserve` (which you really don't need anyway), and you don't need to worry about the final null pointer, because all of the pointers are initialized to null pointers.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Correct. The reserve+push_back is just a hammer I am used to... and you know, when you have a hammer everything looks like nails :) Regarding the *safety*... this solution is **not** safe, it depends on implementation details outside of what the standard guarantees. You either assume the string implementation allows for my answer, or you assume that `execv` won't modify and you use yours... in either case you are crossing your fingers and hoping for the best. This is answer is no better than yours

Answer (score 2):

There are two fundamental problems which need addressing.  The
first is a compiler error: the pointers in the array pointed to
by `myT` are `const`, so you cannot assign to them.  Make `myT`
`char const** myT;`.  The second problem is that what you are
assigning to them is a pointer into a local variable, which
will be destructed when it goes out of scope, so the pointers
will dangle.

Does the function you are calling really need the extra white
space at the end?  (You mentioned `execv` somewhere, I think.
If that's the function, the extra whitespace will do more harm
than good.)  If not, all you have to do is:

```
std::vector<char const*> myT( myVec.size() + 1 );
std::transform( myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), myT.begin(),
                []( std::string const& arg ) { return arg.c_str(); } );
execv( programPath, &myT[0] );
```

If you can't count on C++11 (which is still usually the case),
you can probably do something similar with `boost::bind`;
otherwise, just write the loop yourself.

If you do need to transform the strings in `myVec` in some way,
the best solution is still to copy them into a second
`std::vector<std::string>`, with the transformation, and use
this.

(BTW: do you really want to modify the contents of `myVec`, by
using `+=` on each element in the loop?)

Comment: You could use a non-member function to get the `c_str` from a `string`.

Comment: @PeterWood Non-member function or functional object, but in both cases, you'd need to write something special outside of the current function.